# Display wait time WebDriverWait using selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm interesting in getting the time waited until an object was clickable on the page.
So once the element is clickable a metric is displayed showing how long it took for the element to become active.

```
try:
    WebDriverWait(self.driver,  10, poll_frequency=0.5).until( lambda d: self.submit_button)
except TimeoutException:
    assert False
```

Above is the code that I am using to poll for the element, but I'm looking for a way to get time waited metric out.

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will not get the exact time, as because you have polling every N seconds and the overall wait. But you can have the average approximation.
It's not only for Selenium purposes, but you can use `import time`, for example.

- just before executing the command add: `start = time.time()`
- and right after the command: `end = time.time()`
- then, the needed value will be `print end - start`